# Javascript event handling for Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, event-handling

I am using google maps + javascript + php in my application.
I want to know two things:
 In google maps,

1. does moveend event ALWAYS gets fired
   AFTER zoomend/dragend (whichever of
   two) event occurs.
2. When I click zoom icon on google map
   or scroll the mouse wheel to zoom,
   the zoomend event gets fired more
   than once. If I zoom in one step
   using + icon on map, the zoomend
   event gets fired twice or sometimes
   more. any possible loophole.

   And so want to know **how to stop further event propogation in javascript**. (remember I need not use clearListeners as it will forever ignore event handler which is undesirable).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up listeners for 'moveend', 'zoomend', and 'dragend' to try it out.

```
GEvent.addListener(map, "moveend", function() { console.log('moveend'); });
GEvent.addListener(map, "zoomend", function() { console.log('zoomend'); });
GEvent.addListener(map, "dragend", function() { console.log('dragend'); });
```

It appears that 'moveend' always fires after 'zoomend' or 'dragend'.

However, no events ever fired more than once at a time.  Maybe you accidentally set up two simultaneous listeners.  You shouldn't need to use stopPropagation or cancelBubble.

Answer (score 1):

you could try just reuturning false or null from the event.
If that doesn't work trying using "event.cancelBubble = true" or "event.stopPropagation"

Comment: Use both cancelBubble and stopPropagation(), because some browsers will need the former and some the latter.